# have text appear under picture in smaller "mobile" view

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a site that works great on the desktop mode but when I shrink the page the font stays over the picture and makes it so I cant see the picture and words. How would I adjust the html or css (or both?) to make it so that the font goes below the picture when the site is viewed on a smaller device?

Here's my html and css code:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- {% load static %} -->
<head>

    <!--Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="{% block meta_description %} Welcome to Performance Painting's website {% endblock %}">
    <title> {% block title %}Performance Painting {% endblock %}</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta content="Free HTML Templates" name="keywords">
    <meta content="Free HTML Templates" name="description">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link href="{% static 'website/img/favicon.ico' %}" rel="icon">

    <!-- Google Web Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@400;700&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  

    <!-- Icon Font Stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.4.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Libraries Stylesheet -->
    <link href="{% static 'website/lib/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Customized Bootstrap Stylesheet -->
    <link href="{% static 'website/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Template Stylesheet -->
    <link href="{% static 'website/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Topbar Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary d-none d-lg-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-lg-start mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                        <a class="text-dark py-2 pe-3 border-end border-white" href=""><i class="bi bi-telephone text-secondary me-2"></i>425-330-6295</a>
                        <a class="text-dark py-2 px-3" href=""><i class="bi bi-envelope text-secondary me-2"></i>snazzypainter@gmail.com</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-center text-lg-end">
                    <div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center">
                        <a class="text-body py-2 px-3 border-end border-white" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f text-secondary"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-body py-2 px-3 border-end border-white" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-twitter text-secondary"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-body py-2 px-3 border-end border-white" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in text-secondary"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-body py-2 px-3 border-end border-white" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-instagram text-secondary"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="text-body py-2 ps-3" href="">
                            <i class="fab fa-youtube text-secondary"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Topbar End -->


    <!-- Navbar Start -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark shadow-sm px-5 py-3 py-lg-0">
        <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand p-0">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-uppercase text-primary"><i class="fa fa-paint-roller text-secondary me-3"></i>Performance Painting</h1>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-0 pe-4 border-end border-5 border-primary">
                <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
                <a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
                <a href="{% url 'service' %}" class="nav-item nav-link">Service</a>
                <a href="{% url 'team' %}" class="nav-item nav-link">The Team  </a>
                <a href="{% url 'detail' %}" class="nav-item nav-link">Our Blog</a>
                <a href="{% url 'testimonial' %}" class="nav-item nav-link">Testimonials</a>
                <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class="d-none d-lg-flex align-items-center ps-4">
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-mobile-alt text-secondary me-3"></i>
                <div>
                    <h5 class="text-primary mb-1"><small>Call Now</small></h5>
                    <h6 class="text-light m-0">425-330-6295</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Navbar End -->

    <!-- Hero Start -->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary py-5 bg-hero" style="margin-bottom: 90px;">
        <div class="container py-5">
            <div class="row justify-content-start">
                <div class="col-lg-8 text-center text-lg-start">
                    <h1 class="display-1 text-dark">We Bring Your Home To Lively Colors</h1>
                    <p class="fs-4 text-dark mb-4">Performance Painting is top rated in the Snohomish County
                        With over 30 years in the painting business, we bring quailty and excellence.
                    Thats the PERFORMANCE guarantee! </p>
                    <div class="pt-2">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-secondary rounded-pill py-md-3 px-md-5 mx-2">Get A Quote</a>
                        <a href="{% url 'contact' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary rounded-pill py-md-3 px-md-5 mx-2">Contact Us</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Hero End -->
```

Here's the CSS:

```
/********** Template CSS **********/
:root {
    --primary: #FFE468;
    --secondary: #8CC641;
    --light: #F2F2F2;
    --dark: #272630;
}

.btn {
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: .5s;
}

.btn:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #555555;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #555555;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #555555;
}

.btn.btn-secondary {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn-square {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
}

.btn-sm-square {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
}

.btn-lg-square {
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
}

.btn-square,
.btn-sm-square,
.btn-lg-square {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 35px 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--light);
    outline: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.sticky-top.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover,
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
    color: var(--primary);
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link::before {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        width: 0;
        height: 5px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        background: var(--primary);
        transition: .5s;
    }

    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover::before,
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active::before {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link  {
        margin-left: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
    }
}

.bg-hero {
    background: url(../img/hero.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .bg-hero {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

.about-start,
.about-end {
    background: url(../img/about-bg.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .about-start {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: -90px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .about-end {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -90px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

.service-item,
.contact-item {
    background: url(../img/service.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: .5s;
}

.service-item:hover,
.contact-item:hover {
    background: url(../img/service.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.service-item .service-icon,
.contact-item .contact-icon {
    margin-top: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: var(--secondary);
    background: #FFFFFF;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.service-item .service-icon div,
.contact-item .contact-icon div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: var(--primary);
    transition: .5s;
}

.service-item .service-icon i,
.contact-item .contact-icon i {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: .5s;
}

.service-item:hover .service-icon div,
.contact-item:hover .contact-icon div {
    background: var(--secondary);
}

.service-item:hover .service-icon i,
.contact-item:hover .contact-icon i {
    color: var(--primary);
}

.service-item a.btn {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -30px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.service-item:hover a.btn {
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.bg-quote {
    background: url(../img/quote.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .bg-quote {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

.team-item {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.team-text {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: url(../img/team.jpg) bottom center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 90px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    right: 45px;
    left: 45px;
    bottom: -45px;
    transition: .5s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.team-item:hover .team-text {
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.team-social {
    position: absolute;
    transition: .1s;
    transition-delay: .0s;
    opacity: 0;
}

.team-item:hover .team-social {
    transition-delay: .3s;
    opacity: 1;
}

.bg-testimonial {
    background: url(../img/testimonial.jpg) top left no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .bg-testimonial {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}

.testimonial-carousel .owl-nav {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
}

.testimonial-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev,
.testimonial-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 5px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: var(--secondary);
    font-size: 22px;
    border-radius: 45px;
    transition: .5s;
}

.testimonial-carousel .owl-nav .owl-prev:hover,
.testimonial-carousel .owl-nav .owl-next:hover {
    color: var(--dark);
}

.testimonial-carousel .owl-item img {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.bg-call-to-action {
    background: url(../img/call-to-action.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

.bg-footer {
    background: url(../img/footer.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .bg-call-to-action,
    .bg-footer {
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK I suggest create 2 texts: one for big screens with class d-none & d-lg-block and the second for d-block and d-lg-none. Look of the classes name at the bootstrap documentations and you will get what I mean

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That little trick worked. I'm able to hide the text in the smaller version!

Answer (score 1):

You can use "@media" to do so. Here's how it will go:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .myclass {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

You can adjust the amount of pixels. If you want to learn more about @media, check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp